# Upload large amount of files to Google Storage bucket with Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to transfer about 300,000 files (about 1.5TB) to a Google Cloud bucket.

The challenges:

- This is from a remote source, so is it possible to use a proxy with
  with the upload function?
- This may take several days. So how to best
  run a process this long? App Engine service, Compute Engine instance,
  something else?

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library.
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const db = require('../models');

// Instantiates a client. If you don't specify credentials when constructing
// the client, the client library will look for credentials in the
// environment.
const storage = new Storage();

const bucketName = "bucket-name";
const increment = 5;

let globalCounter = 0;

function getPDFLinks(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const dbRecords = [/*Array of URLs from our db*/];
        const dlLinkArray = dbRecords.map(link => ({
            link: 'https://sample.domain.com' + link.dataValues.downloadLink,
            filename: link.dataValues.contentID
        }));
        console.log("dlLinkArray Length: ", dlLinkArray.length);
        downloadPDFsSlow(dlLinkArray, 0)
        .then(x => {
            console.log("finished all downloads and updated SQL");
            resolve(x);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}

function downloadPDFsSlow(linksArray, counter){ //<increment> promises at a time. x{link: url, filename: contnetID}
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all(linksArray.slice(counter, counter+increment).map(x => uploadFile(bucketName, x.link, x.filename) ))
        .then(() => {
            //console.log("Map uploadFile results: ", x);
            globalCounter++;
            console.log('globalCounter: ', globalCounter);
            if(linksArray.length > counter){ //have not reached the end of URLs
                const toUpdate = linksArray.slice(counter, counter+increment).map(x => x.filename);
                updateRecords(toUpdate); //ASYNC
                setTimeout(() => downloadPDFsSlow(linksArray, counter+increment), 1000);
            }
            else{ //Reached the end
                console.log("DONE");
                resolve(`downloadPDFsSlow completed ${linksArray.length} records`);
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
            //log error, log slide of arrays that caused error, call next slice of downloadPDFsSlow
            if(linksArray.length > counter){
                console.log("Skipping to next. Counter: ", counter);
                    setTimeout(() => downloadPDFsSlow(linksArray, counter+increment), 1000);
            }else{
                reject('downloadPDFsSlow FAILED at the end' + JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        });
    });
}

function uploadFile(bucketName, fileURL, reName) { //uploads fileURL, deletes if too small, else renames to contentID.pdf
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        /**
         * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
         */
        // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
        // const filename = 'Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';

        // Uploads a local file to the bucket
        storage
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .upload(fileURL, {
            // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
            gzip: true,
            metadata: {
                // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
                // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
                // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
                cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
            },
            })
            .then((x) => {
                console.log("SIZE: ", x[1].size);
                if(x[1].size <= 202 || (x[1].size <= 13236 && x[1].size >= 13234)){ //check file size, if small then PDF not available
                    deleteFile(bucketName, x[1].name)
                    .then(d => resolve(d))
                    .catch(e => reject(e));
                }else{
                    //console.log(`${fileURL} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
                    renameFile(bucketName, x[1].name, "pdf/" + reName + ".pdf")
                    .then( renameResult => {
                        //console.log(renameResult);
                        resolve(x);
                    })
                    .catch(e => reject(e));
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
                reject(err);
            });
        // [END storage_upload_file]
    });
}
  
function listFiles(bucketName) {

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';

// Lists files in the bucket
storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .getFiles()
    .then(results => {
    const files = results[0];

    console.log('Files:');
    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file.name);
    });
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
// [END storage_list_files]
}

function renameFile(bucketName, srcFilename, destFilename) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        /**
         * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
         */
        // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
        // const srcFilename = 'File to move, e.g. file.txt';
        // const destFilename = 'Destination for file, e.g. moved.txt';

        // Moves the file within the bucket
        storage
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .file(srcFilename)
            .move(destFilename)
            .then((x) => {
                console.log(
                    `gs://${bucketName}/${srcFilename} moved to gs://${bucketName}/${destFilename}.`
                );
                resolve(x);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('ERROR:', err);
                reject(err);
            });
        // [END storage_move_file]
    });
}

function deleteFile(bucketName, filename) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        /**
         * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
         */
        // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
        // const filename = 'File to delete, e.g. file.txt';
    
        // Deletes the file from the bucket
        storage
        .bucket(bucketName)
        .file(filename)
        .delete()
        .then((x) => {
            console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
            resolve(x);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
            reject(err);
        });
        // [END storage_delete_file]
    });
}

function updateRecords(recordsToUpdate){
    db.sequelize.sync({force: false}).then(function(){
        Promise.all(recordsToUpdate.map(x => db.Record.update({localFile: x + '.pdf'}, {where: { contentID: x }})))
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Updated filename");
            //db.sequelize.close();
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
    });
}

//EXECUTE
getPDFLinks()
    .then(x => {
        console.log("getPDFLinks COMPLETE");
        console.log(x);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error("getPDFLinks FAILED");
        console.error(e);
    });
```

Comment: Please provide some more details so that we can better understand the problem. Is it a requirement that you use this node.js code? What and where is the process that governs the process? Something needs to iterate over the source files,  perform the uploads, and ensure that everything is uploaded. Where do you anticipate this running? How does it access the files? To stop asking questions, you could use `gsutil` multi-threaded to upload the files to a source bucket (this supports resumable uploads too) and trigger a Cloud Function that does your transformation.

Comment: I added the complete script to the code snippet. This runs as a service under App Engine, standard environment, basic scaling. The function is triggered by a route in Express Server. This worked for a couple of thousand files. However, the source server returns 403 errors after a few requests. Also, apparently App Engine processes timeout after 10 minutes.

Comment: Yes, you'll hit request timeouts trying to do this a one synchronous lump. I recommend you look into Task Queues (Cloud Tasks). An good approach would be to create Tasks for each of (perhaps batches) of your dbRecords. Then the worker process pulls each file and applies your transformation before persisting the result to GCS. This approach gives your parallelism, shorter requests, async and retries.

Comment: I looked into Task Queues (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/). Looks like it is not available for Node.js. Is there a way to do this with a Node.js app?

Comment: @DazWilkin can you please provide your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look into Task Queues ([Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/)).

A good approach would be to create Tasks for each of (perhaps batches) of your dbRecords. Then the worker process pulls each file and applies your transformation before persisting the result to GCS. This approach gives your parallelism, shorter requests, async and retries.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/tasks